# Is there any way to simplify this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

I am trying to get the Voltage across R2, R5. Could someone explain with detailed steps? Thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck? You need to show effort in solving your homework problems.

Comment: You tagged this with Kirchhoff's Law.  That, of course, is how to solve this.

Comment: *Is there any way to simplify this circuit?* Sure, resistors in parallel or in series can be reduced to one resistor, I see at least one such a simplification. Do you see it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never underestimate the power of using your eyes and redrawing stuff to remove clutter. Making stuff de-cluttered makes things simpler and allows you to find an answer. Here's a simple helping hand for what you do next: -

[image]

No more clues; you should be able to solve this yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still having a hard time rearranging circuits like this, but i guess the only way is to practice more